# K_SPACE none responsive

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing my first pygame script, but the K_SPACE event does not work. When the script is run, nothing happens when the space bar is pressed. I have changed K_SPACE to K_LEFT and K_LSHIFT and they work absolutely fine, so I don't think the error is in the code itself?

The Input is mid-way through the code but I wanted to include it all to ensure there were no issues above which were causing it.
Any ideas?

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
background = pygame.image.load('space.jpg')

playerImg = pygame.image.load('battleship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

enemy1Img = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
enemy1X = random.randint(0,800)
enemy1Y = random.randint(50,150)
enemy1X_change = 0.1
enemy1Y_change = 40

laserImg = pygame.image.load('laser.png')
laserX = 0
laserY = 480
laserX_change = 0
laserY_change = 0.5
laser_state = "ready"


def player(x, y):
 screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX,playerY))
def enemy1(x, y):
 screen.blit(enemy1Img, (enemy1X, enemy1Y))
def fire_laser(x, y):
 global laser_state
 laser_state = "fire"
 screen.blit(laserImg, (x+30, y+10))

running = True
while running:

 screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
 screen.blit(background, (0,0))

 for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         running = False

 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
         playerX_change = -0.1
     elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
         playerX_change = 0.1
     elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
         if laser_state == 'ready':
             laserX = playerX
             fire_laser(laserX, laserY)

 if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
     if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
         playerX_change = 0



 playerX += playerX_change
 if playerX <= 0:
     playerX = 0
 if playerX >= 736:
     playerX = 736

 enemy1X += enemy1X_change
 if enemy1X <= 0:
     enemy1X_change = 0.1
     enemy1Y += enemy1Y_change
 elif enemy1X >= 736:
     enemy1X_change = -0.1
     enemy1Y += enemy1Y_change

 if laserY <= 0:
     laserY = 480
     laser_state = 'ready'
 if laser_state == "fire":
     fire_laser(laserX,laserY)
     laserY -= laserY_change

 player(playerX, playerY)
 enemy1(enemy1X, enemy1Y)
 pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with your orignal code.

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to handle the events in the event loop not after the event loop.

Move the event handling in the event loop:

```py
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->| 

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if laser_state == 'ready':
                    laserX = playerX
                    fire_laser(laserX, laserY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
```

Comment: How would that be different for the space key rather than any other, changing K_SPACE to K_LSHIFT for example, with no change in indentation, would work perfectly fine?

Comment: @isaacjoel If you do the event handling after the loop, you just handle the last event in the loop. Events may get lost. I've test the code in your question and the code in my answer. I've verified that my solution fixes your bug.

Comment: Wow, so rudimentary I didn't even notice it. Well done!

Comment: That's fixed it, Thank you again!